# How to reply to Python's GNU mailman 3 mailing list

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, python, gnu, mailing-lists

Sometimes I find myself trying to reply to Python's mailing list, but continuously failing. Python's GNU Mailman 2 did not have these issues while Mailman 3 does. There are some conventions Python uses in Mailman 3. Like "RE: RE: Title" means reply to a reply, so the interface updates itself accordingly. The question is what are the conventions I need to follow to have,

```
At <time> Someone wrote:
> A part of the message I'm replying to
Some reply
> another part
another reply
```

Also how do I have my email signature in the reply message?